# Automatically Login after Registration success ( Yii Framework )

Tags: php, yii

I have a registration form, then I want to do an automatic login after the registration is successful. I already tried it, but it doesn't automatically login after a successful registration.

This is my ActionRegister function:

```
public function actionRegister(){

   $model = new User;

 if(isset($_POST['User'])){
    $model->username = $_POST['User']['username'];
    $model->password = $model->hashPassword($_POST['User']['password']);
    $model->email = $_POST['User']['email'];

    $identity=new LoginForm();
    $identity->username=$model->username;
    $identity->password=$model->password;

 if($model->save()) {
    $identity->login();
    $this->redirect(array('index'));
    } 
 } 
     $this->render('register',array('model'=>$model,'));
 }
```

*UPDATED and EDITED*

this is my login() function in model LoginForm

```
   public function login()
   {
    if($this->_identity===null)
    {
        $this->_identity=new UserIdentity($this->username,$this->password);
        $this->_identity->authenticate();
    }
    if($this->_identity->errorCode===UserIdentity::ERROR_NONE)
    {
        $duration=$this->rememberMe ? 3600*24*30 : 0; // 30 days
        Yii::app()->user->login($this->_identity,$duration);
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

and this is my UserIdentity.php

```
  class UserIdentity extends CUserIdentity
  {
  private $_id;
  private $level;

  public function authenticate()
  {
  $record=user::model()->findByAttributes(array('username'=>$this->username));
  if($record===null)
   $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID;
  else if($record->password!==md5($this->password))
   $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_PASSWORD_INVALID; 

  else
 { 
 $this->_id=$record->id;
 $this->username=$record->username;
 $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_NONE;
 }

 return $this->errorCode==self::ERROR_NONE;
 }

public function getId(){
return $this->_id;
}

}
```

Is there any problem in my code? I'll appreciate any of your help and solution.

Best Regards.
Rafly.

Comment: show me the login() function in LoginForm() model ... also UserIdentity.php in Components folder

Comment: @JaiminMosLake i already added Useridentity.php and login() function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already solved my own question , just change the return value of authenticate function become

```
return !$this->errorCode;
```

Answer (score 0):

This one works for me

```
if ($model->save()) { //If regisrtation success
    $login = new LoginForm;
    $login->username = $_POST['User']['userName'];
    $login->password = $_POST['User']['password'];
    if ($login->validate() && $login->login()) {
        //Redirect home page
    }
}
```

And make sure no issue in registration also..

Comment: It still same , still not doing automatic login after registrated.
and it doesn't redirected after do registrated.

Maybe I have in problem on UserIdentity.php and function login() at model LoginForm..

Answer (score -1):

```
// your code
    $identity=new LoginForm();
    $identity->username=$model->username;
    $identity->password=$model->password;

//  Try this
    $identity=new LoginForm();
    $identity->username=$model->username;
    $identity->password=$_POST['User']['password'];
```

As in $model->password you getting encrypted password. Not Exact password.

I think this will work